# Как сделать расстояние между тегами TR?

Tags: css3, html5

Решил для себя сделать мини иконки для гитхаба типа "версия" или "в разработке". Сделал в виде таблиц, но мне не нравится то, что если ширина одного `TD` изменится, то у остальных тоже (короче хочу переделать на div'ы, но никак). Расстояние - имеется ввиду расстояние между одной строкой и другой.

[image: Слипшиеся TR теги]
**Код: https://jsfiddle.net/7cw0c57v/**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.VERSION_text {
  background-color: #5b5b5b;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.VERSION {
  background-color: #5BC60E;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_2 {
  background-color: #97C40E;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_3 {
  background-color: #D1AE26;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_4 {
  background-color: #ee8246;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_5 {
  background-color: #D16450;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_6 {
  background-color: #307ABD;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_7 {
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

tr {}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_2" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_3" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_4" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_5" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_6" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_7" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**(Кому нечем занятся: прошу переделать эту табличную фигню на нормальные div'ы)**

Comment: Убери `border-spacing: 0;`

Comment: Угу, только td "VERSION_text" и "VERSION_№" тоже раезжаются. Мне надо, чтоб между tr'ками было расстояние.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет избавиться от таблицы и сверстать ее на флексах, тогда будут тебе доступны какие угодно отступы.

Но если охота поизвращяться, то на, но никому не рассказывай что это я посоветовал:

```
td {
 border: 10px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Не так вопрос задал. Мне надо, чтобы между TR'ками было расстояние. А флексы не кросбраузерны.

Comment: А что тебе мешает задать   `border-top: 1px solid white` или `border-bottom: 1px solid white`?

Comment: Timoha_Timohavich, ты ошибаешься (https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Пользуйся флексами и не делай таких извращений. Если ни в какую не хочешь флексы, делай сетку.

Answer (score 1):

`border-spacing` который вы свели к нулю отвечает как раз за расстояние между ячейками. Измените его на:

```
border-spacing: 0 10px;
```

и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 1):

**[Ответ уже дали.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780835/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/780837#780837)**

---

**[BraFik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/264868/brafik) says:**

> Так? Я добавил в начале кода
>
> ```
> table{
>       border-spacing:  0 11px;
>     }
> ```
>
> ```css
> > 
> >       * { margin: 0; padding: 0; border-spacing: 0; background: transparent; background-color: transparent; }
> > 
> >     table{
> >       border-spacing:  0 11px;
> >     }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_text {  
> >        background-color: #5b5b5b; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px; 
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION {
> >        background-color: #5BC60E; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_2 {
> >        background-color: #97C40E; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_3 {
> >        background-color: #D1AE26; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_4 {
> >        background-color: #ee8246; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_5 {
> >        background-color: #D16450; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_6 {
> >        background-color: #307ABD; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> > 
> >       .VERSION_7 {
> >        background-color: #9C9C9C; 
> >        padding: 6px;
> >        height: 20px; 
> >        width: 88px; 
> >        color: white;
> >        text-align: center;
> >        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
> >       }
> >         
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> >     <html>
> >      <head>
> >       <title></title>
> >      </head>
> >      <body>
> >       <table align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_2" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_3" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_4" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_5" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_6" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> > 
> >        <tr>
> >         <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
> >         <td class="VERSION_7" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
> >        </tr>
> >       </table>
> >      </body>
> >     </html>
> > 
> >
> ```