# Как разделить строки таблицы?

Tags: css3, html5, табличная-верстка

Всем добрый вечер (или утро). Сделал себе мини иконки на гидхаб, но они слишком плотно налеплены. Даже прямо склеились. Как разделить теги TR между собой?
[image: Слипшиеся TR теги]
**Код: https://jsfiddle.net/7cw0c57v/**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.VERSION_text {
  background-color: #5b5b5b;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.VERSION {
  background-color: #5BC60E;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_2 {
  background-color: #97C40E;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_3 {
  background-color: #D1AE26;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_4 {
  background-color: #ee8246;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_5 {
  background-color: #D16450;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_6 {
  background-color: #307ABD;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.VERSION_7 {
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 88px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

tr {}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_2" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_3" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_4" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_5" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_6" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_7" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**(Кому нечем занятся: прошу переделать эту табличную фигню на нормальные div'ы)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так? Я добавил в начале кода

```
table{
      border-spacing:  0 11px;
    }
```

```css
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; border-spacing: 0; background: transparent; background-color: transparent; }

table{
  border-spacing:  0 11px;
}

  .VERSION_text {  
   background-color: #5b5b5b; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px; 
  }

  .VERSION {
   background-color: #5BC60E; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_2 {
   background-color: #97C40E; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_3 {
   background-color: #D1AE26; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_4 {
   background-color: #ee8246; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_5 {
   background-color: #D16450; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_6 {
   background-color: #307ABD; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }

  .VERSION_7 {
   background-color: #9C9C9C; 
   padding: 6px;
   height: 20px; 
   width: 88px; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_2" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_3" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_4" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_5" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_6" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="VERSION_text" valign="middle">VERSION</td>
    <td class="VERSION_7" valign="middle">0.0.0.2v</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Братан, спасибо! Выручил!! ;)